# Nestjs Typeorm find method not getting repository records

Tags: mysql, node.js, backend, nestjs, typeorm

I setup NestJS project with TypeORM and Mysql2 and have a "**Client**" entity for OAuth clients table.

The table name is "**clients**" and everything is OK in my codes as I reviewed it many times.

I created two clients with "**save**" method and now I want to get them with find, findOne, getMany, getOne but I got no result. Here is my code:

**client.entity.ts**

```js
import { PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, Entity, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';
import { AccessToken } from '../../access-tokens/entities/access-token.entity';
    
@Entity({ name: 'clients' })
export class Client {
      @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
      id!: number;
    
      @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 40, unique: true })
      name!: string;
    
      @Column({ type: 'nvarchar', nullable: false, default: 'secret_key' })
      secret!: string;
    
      @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 20 })
      type!: string;
    
      @Column({ type: 'bit', default: false })
      revoked!: boolean;
    
      @OneToMany(() => AccessToken, (accessToken) => accessToken.client, {
        cascade: true,
      })
      accessTokens?: AccessToken[];
}
```

**clients.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Client } from './entities/client.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
    
@Injectable()
export class ClientsService {
      constructor(@InjectRepository(Client) private clientRepository: Repository<Client>) {}
    
      async findAll(): Promise<Client[]> {
        return await this.clientRepository.find();
      }
}
```

**clients.module.ts**

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientsService } from './clients.service';
import { ClientsController } from './clients.controller';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Client } from './entities/client.entity';
import { ClientSubscriber } from './client.subscriber';
    
@Module({
      imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Client])],
      controllers: [ClientsController],
      providers: [ClientsService, ClientSubscriber],
      exports: [ClientsService],
})
export class ClientsModule {}
```

**ormconfig.json**

```json
{
      "type": "mysql",
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 3306,
      "username": "admin",
      "password": "**********",
      "database": "db_name",
      "entities": [
        "./dist/**/*.entity.js"
      ],
      "synchronize": false,
      "migrationsTableName": "migrations",
      "migrations": [
        "./dist/migrations/*.js"
      ],
      "cli": {
        "migrationsDir": "./src/migrations"
      },
      "migrationsRun": false,
      "logging": [
        "error"
      ]
}
```

I tested with raw query by entity manager and I got the correct result of clients records. please help me if you had any experience with **TypeORM**.